# Strange standard output behavior when blocking thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a C# application that creates a thread which talks to Node.js (node.exe) over standard input.

The code to create this is pretty standard:

```
  ProcessStartInfo NodeStart = new ProcessStartInfo();
  NodeStart.FileName = FileName; // node.exe
  NodeStart.Arguments = Arguments; 

  NodeStart.CreateNoWindow = true;
  NodeStart.RedirectStandardError = true; 
  NodeStart.RedirectStandardInput = true;
  NodeStart.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  NodeStart.UseShellExecute = false; 

  process = new Process();
  process.OutputDataReceived += ReceivedOutput;
  process.StartInfo = NodeStart;
  process.Start();
  process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

The code works completely OK as long as I do not block the thread that is running it by using Thread.WaitOne(). As soon as I call Thread.WaitOne() something goes wrong with the input/output of the process. Next time I unblock the thread and write to standard input, I get nothing back. I inspected the process object in the debugger prior to when the standard input gets written and nothing appears to be wrong (node.exe is running and accepts the standard input).

It may simply be the case that standard input/output breaks when the thread blocks, but is this true? I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/

Comment: Impossible to know what the problem is without a good [mcve]. One apparent problem in the code you did post is that you redirect stderr but never read from it (e.g. subscribe to and enable the `ErrorDataReceived` event). Your problem might be deadlock, if e.g. you are creating and waiting for the process in a UI thread and in your I/O handler attempt to invoke something on the UI thread. Please improve the question so there's enough information to answer it.